# 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_dataframe'

Tags: dataframe

I'm sure I have a small error here that I'm overlooking, but am having a tough time figuring out what I need to change.

Here is my code up until the error I'm getting.

```
# Load libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas.tools.plotting import scatter_matrix
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.discriminant_analyisis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.svm import SVC

# Load dataset
names = ['action','reject','approve','occ','loanamt', 'suffolk', 'appinc','typur','unit','married','dep','emp',yjob','self','atotinc','cototinc','hexp']

# from azureml import Workspace
# ws = Workspace(
#      workspace_id='',
#      authorization_token='==',
#      endpoint='https://studioapi.azureml.net'
# )
# ds = ws.datasets['loanapp_c.csv']

ds = pd.read_csv('desktop/python ML/loanapp_c.csv')
dataset = ds.to_dataframe()
```

I was running this on Azure and am now trying to do it locally. Here is the error I'm getting:

```
AttributeError                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-b49a23658806> in <module>()
     32
     33 ds = pd.read_csv('desktop/python ML/loanapp_c.csv')
---> 34 dataset = ds.to_dataframe()
     35
     36 # shape

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in_getattr_(self, name)
     4374 if self._info_axis.can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
            return self[name]
  -> 4376 return object._getattribute_(self,name)
     4377
     4378 def _setattr_(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_dataframe'
```

Not sure what I have wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `pd.read_csv()` is already a DataFrame and thus that kind of object does not support calling `.to_dataframe()`.

You can check the type of your variable `ds` using `print(type(ds))`, you will see that it is a pandas DataFrame type.

Answer (score 1):

According to what I understand. You are loading `loanapp_c.csv` in `ds` using this code:

```
ds = pd.read_csv('desktop/python ML/loanapp_c.csv')
```

`ds` over here is a DataFrame object. What you are doing is calling `to_dataframe` on an object which a DataFrame already.

Removing this `dataset = ds.to_dataframe()` from your code should solve the error

Comment: I just set dataset = ds and that fixed it. Thanks for your help!